# Convert comma-separated fields to concat() function

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, converters

I have a `table_product` that contains comma-separated strings;

```
id | products
-----------
1  | tv,phone,tablet
2  | computer,tv
3  | printer,tablet,radio
```

To avoid manual concatenation, like `concat(tv,',',phone,',',tablet)`

I want to select the data from `table_product.products` as `concat()` statement.

Tried this, but getting an error:

```
select concat(select products from table_product where id=1) from table_sales
```

Is there any short and basic way to perform this query?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected result should be. your example `concat(tv,',',phone,',',tablet)` would return exactly what you currently have. Or do you want to return the SQL code?

Comment: Instead of concatenating manually like `concat(tv,',',phone,',',tablet)`, I want comma separated text from products column to be  returned/converted to the sql code.

Comment: Why don't you fix your data model? That's where the problem starts, multiple values in a single column.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Please add expected query output for the given example to your question

Comment: @ S-Man I just want to return this `concat(select products from table_product where id=1)` code to `concat(tv,',',phone,',',tablet)` query, so that i will be able to select concatenated products from `table_sales`

Comment: Besides that, as @Frank, mentioned storing multiple values in a single column is almost never a good idea, it sounds like the entries in the text field are actually the names of the columns you want to select from the table_sales table. This is even worse since you'd probably need an `EXECUTE` statement just to get the text to be usable as column names. You'll be much better off revising your data and application model instead.

Comment: @ Nathan thanks for the suggestion, can you please provide any alternative options as sample to test please. thanks

Comment: The table_product table should be refactored such that each product is its own row, so a serial id column, int group_id column and text product column. So there would be 3 rows for group 1, 2 rows for group 2 and 3 rows for group 3. You can then query the relevant columns based on the group_id. When it comes to creating the concat statement I would recommend handling this on an application level rather then doing it in pure SQL, so whatever is running the queries should take the products from the table_products table and make a sql injection safe concat for the table_sales query.

Comment: @ Nathan as suggested, i have refactored the table of [tbale_product](https://dbfiddle.uk/dnbi29hk), so can you provide a query to select the data from table_sales based on table_product2 please. Thanks

Comment: You're missing my point, I don't think it's wise to do all of this fully in sql at all. I think you'll be better off first querying table_products in some script and then creating and a query on table_sales using the output of that query. You want to use the products in table_products as column names rather than strings and getting that working using just sql is more work then it's worth imo. You might even be able to replace the entire table_product table with a bunch of if statement in your script it's not too long.

Comment: Also, I can see that table_sales contains both text and int colums. Store everything either as int or text columns (judging from the data these columns should all be of type int), otherwise you'll give yourself another headache keeping track off the data type of each column as well and having to cast them accordingly.